# PostAsync файл MultiPartFormData с кириллическими символами

Tags: c#, request, кириллица, httpclient

Пытаюсь отправить документ с кириллическими символами в названии через телеграм-бот:

```
MultipartFormDataContent o = new MultipartFormDataContent();
o.Add(new StreamContent(new FileStream("Path//to//file//with//cyrillic//symbols", FileMode.Open)), "document", Path.GetFileName("Path//to//file//with//cyrillic//symbols");
message = await client.PostAsync(uri, o);
```

Но при наличии кириллицы получаю файл с именем вроде "= utf 8 B ASD78asd8asd9...== =". Латиница и цифры воспринимаются нормально. Через NodeJS тоже всё прекрасно работает. Как я могу отправить файл с кириллическим названием через httpclient multipart/form-data?

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955802/2881286)

Comment: Мне кажется, я попробовал всё.
`fs.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                        {
                            Name="document",
                            FileName = "кириллица.xlsx"
                        };`
И в этом случае тоже кириллицу заменяет на текст `"=?utf-8?B?0YXRg9C5Lnhsc3g=?="`
Действительно нет "промышленного" решения этой проблемы?

Comment: Твой пример отличается от того, что в ответах по ссылке

Answer (score 1):

Стандартная кодировка строки `.NET` это как ни странно, ни `windows-1251`, ни `UTF8` и даже не `UTF16`.

Кодировка у .NET строк отсутствует в случае если вы не обращали на это внимание, но она все же есть. И кодировкой всех строковых литералов в `.NET` является `UTF-16LE`.

Для того что бы решить вашу проблему поступим так:

1. Извлечем массив байтов из исходной строки
2. Запросим перекодировку у класса `Encoding` воспользовавшись статическим методом `Convert`
3. Сохраним строку в кодировку `UTF8` и запишем ее в переменную. (*вашем случае в поток*).

---

```
string resultUtf8 = string.Empty;
Encoding utf16enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-16LE");
Encoding utf8enc = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] tmpUtf16LeArr = utf16enc.GetBytes("Some UTF-16LE строка—©日本語");
resultUtf8 = utf8enc.GetString(Encoding.Convert(utf16enc, utf8enc, tmpUtf16LeArr));
```

На выходе получим оригинальную строку, но в кодировку `UTF8`.

[Test IDEone](https://ideone.com/SHoDEP)

Comment: @Test IDEone
Конкретно ваш вариант не сработал. Результат тот же, что и изначально. Видимо, что-то не так, Проблема возникает именно в тот момент, когда я передаю эту строку в MultipartFormDataContent.Add

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря комментариям @Grundy так сработало:

```
MultipartFormDataContent o = new MultipartFormDataContent();
StreamContent fs = new StreamContent(new FileStream("cyrillic_name", FileMode.Open));
String headerValue = "form-data; name=\"document\"; filename=\"cyrillic_name\"";
fs.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", FixEnc(headerValue));
o.Add(fs, "document", "whatever");

private string FixEnc(string source)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
    source = "";
    foreach (byte b in bytes)
    {
        source += (Char)b;
    }
    return source;
}
```

Такой вариант оказался нерабочим для различных спецсимволов. Но пришло понимание, что Telegram корректно принимает строки, если ему передать их \uXXXX коды. Здесь уже, видимо, совсем школьная задача передать строку, в которой будет написано "\u20bd" для символа рубля, а не "\ \u20bd". Формирую я эту строку через следующий код:

```
        string StrOut = "";
        foreach (Char c in source)
        {
            string ss = Convert.ToString(c, 16);
            string s = new string('0',4 - ss.Length);
            StrOut += @"\u"+s+ss;
        }
        return StrOut;
```

Но в результате я получаю именно "\ \uXXXX", а не "\uXXXX", Как передать символ корректно?

Comment: У `Encoding` есть метод `GetString` дабы не крутить в цикле байты. `fs.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headerValue))));`

Comment: @Yami подобные варианты я пробовал. И даже конкретно ваш вставил, чтобы перепроверить. Не работает.

Comment: Вам известна исходная кодировка строки?

Comment: @Yami Encoding.Default? Да, известна. Судя по всему, это win1251. На англоязычном форуме мы уже пришли к тому, что этот вариант неверный в силу того, что далеко не все символы однобайтовые. И действительно, спец-символы отражаются криво.

Comment: Хорошо, обойдем данную ситуацию так как будет в ответе.